# How to update the data in the drop-down list after closing the modal window

Tags: reactjs

I have a component (React) with select and with button, which open modal window with inputs. When I click "Save" button in modal window, I add data from inputs to database (using fetch) and close modal window.

I need, that new data shows in select, after closing modal window. But now there are showing only after reloading page. How to fix it?

**Component with fetch:**

```
class MainPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      event: []
      }
    };   
  } 

  onHandleEventFetch() {
    fetch(`${Config.baseUrl}/event`, {
      method: 'GET'
    })
            .then((response) => {
              if (response.status >= 400) {
                throw new Error('Bad response from server');
              }
              return response.json();
            })
            .then(data =>
                this.setState({ event: data })
            );
  }

render() {
    return (
      ...
              <InputTypeEvent event={this.props.event}
          onhandleEventFetch={this.props.onhandleEventFetch}
        />
            ...
    );
  }
}
```

**Component with select:**

```
class InputTypeEvent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modalIsOpen: false
    };    
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    Modal.setAppElement('body');
  }  

  handleOpenModal() {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: true });
  }

  onHandleCloseModal() {
    this.props.onhandleEventFetch();
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal
          isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
          contentLabel='Example Modal'
          style={customStyles}
        >
          <EventPage onhandleCloseModal={this.onHandleCloseModal}/>
        </Modal>       
        <select>          
          {this.props.event.map(item => {
            return (<InputTypeEventSelect key={item.id} directory={item}/>); // options are here
          })}
        </select>       
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Component in modal window:**

```
class EventPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);    
  }   

handleSaveExit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onhandleCloseModal();      
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        <a href='#' role='button' onClick={this.handleSaveExit}>
          Save
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My code work on Firefox, but doesn't work in Chrome

Comment: Instead of passing data from one component to another, I would suggest that you make an API call to get updated data from database after closing modal. Then use setState to add that data in your state object.

Comment: Are you sure that you are passing the right handler from the MainPage component? Looks like in `onhandleEventFetch={this.props.onhandleEventFetch}` you are passing some `this.props.onhandlerEventFetch`, but as I can see from the code you should, as already mentioned, bind your handler in MaintComponent constructor and then pass handler as prop like this `onhandleEventFetch={this.onHandleEventFetch}`  - not this.props, but `this.onHandler`

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `onHandleEventFetch` to the `this` context of `MainPage`. Because of the way `this` works in js, `this.setState({ event: data })` is adding `event` to `InputTypeEvent's state` instead of `MainPage's state`.

Doing

```
   this.onHandleEventFetch = this.onHandleEventFetch.bind(this)
```

in the constructor of `MainPage` component will make sure `this.setState({ event: data })` is called on the correct componenet.

consider doing this

```
    class MainPage extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
          event: this.props.event // changes made here
        }
        this.onHandleEventFetch = this.onHandleEventFetch.bind(this)
      };   
      } 

    onHandleEventFetch() {
       fetch(`${Config.baseUrl}/event`, {
        method: 'GET'
      })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.status >= 400) {
            throw new Error('Bad response from server');
          }
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(data =>
            this.setState({ event: data })
        );
     }

      render() {
         return (
            ...
          <InputTypeEvent event={this.state.event} // changes made here
             onhandleEventFetch={this.onHandleEventFetch} // changes made here
         />
        ...
       );
      }
     }
```

Comment: I have it in my code, I cut it there. 
Maybe I need use async/await?

Comment: And my code work on Firefox, but doesn't work in Chrome

Comment: You are setting state in your `then` function but you are passing ` this.props.event` to `InputTypeEvent` when the state gets updated here ` this.setState({ event: data })` the props passed down is still the old events object